# How to display an ordered doubly linked list backwards?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm struggling with this. I've got it to display most of the list, but one of the 1's is not showing up, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

Here is the relevant code, I think.

My insert function:

```
 template <class T>
 void DoublyLinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
 {
    DoublyLinkedList<T> *newNode, *tmp, *oneBefore;

    newNode = new DoublyLinkedList(data);

if (mNext == NULL)
    mNext = newNode;

else
{
   oneBefore = mNext;
   tmp = mNext;

    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->mData < data)
    {
        oneBefore = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->mNext;
    }

    if (tmp == mNext)
    {
        newNode->mNext = mNext;
        mNext = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        oneBefore->mNext = newNode;
        newNode->mNext = tmp;
        newNode->mPrevious = oneBefore;
    }

   }
 }
```

My displayBackwards function:

```
 void displayBackward(DoublyLinkedList<int> *ptr)
 {
    DoublyLinkedList<int> *tmp;

    tmp = ptr;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
       cout << tmp->getData() << endl;
       tmp = tmp->getPrevious();
    }
 }
```

And the relevant part of my main function:

```
    DoublyLinkedList<int> *ptr, *head, *tail;

    ptr = new DoublyLinkedList<int>;

    cout << "Testing Insert\n";
    ptr->insert(1);
    ptr->insert(2);
    ptr->insert(3);
    ptr->insert(1);

    tail = ptr;
    while (tail->getNext() != NULL)
       tail = tail->getNext();

    cout << "\n\nTesting displayBackward\n";
    displayBackward(tail);
```

My output currently is:

```
 Testing displayBackward
 3
 2
 1
```

Comment: @Mark: It's a free-floating C-style doubly linked list, not a C++ `std::list` like one within a bound container.

Comment: @Xeo and user1698667, sorry - my comment was based on the title of the question, not the actual question itself. I withdraw it and apologize for the snark. P.S. You might try to change the title to be more representative of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the problem (in the insert function)

```
    if (tmp == mNext)
    {
        newNode->mNext = mNext;
        mNext = newNode;
    }
```

You need

```
    if (tmp == mNext)
    {
        newNode->mNext = mNext;
        mNext->mPrevious = newNode;
        mNext = newNode;
    }
```

Your original code will work in cases except when you try to insert data which is less than or equal to the data in your current first node.

Also, I am assuming you constructor initializes mNext & mPrevious to NULL. If not, you will have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
 template <class T>
 void DoublyLinkedList<T>::insert(T data)
 {
    DoublyLinkedList<T> *newNode, *tmp, *oneBefore;

    newNode = new DoublyLinkedList(data);

if (mNext == NULL)
    mNext = newNode;

else
```

This isn't linking up the new node's back pointer.

There may be more wrong with your code also.

---

An easy way to code up a doubly linked list is to

- differentiate between *list* and *node* type, and
- make each list always have one dummy node, called a **header node**.

That way you will have no `NULL` pointers to deal with.

It really simplifies things.

Comment: Can you explain to me how I could fix that issue? I know its a problem with the insert function.

Comment: @user1698667: fixing "isn't linking up" involves linking up. You don't show any type definition so it's impossible to know what you've called the back pointer member. I think it could be a good idea to study the concept of a *doubly* linked list, because apparently you're treating it as just a singly linked list.

Comment: The back pointer member is called "mPrevious", it's there in my insert function... I understand the concept of the doubly linked list, but I'm struggling with the implementation.